# Integral domain of a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring over an integral domain. Let $a, b \in A$ where $(a) = (b)$. Show that there exists invertible elements $x$ and $y$ in $A$ such that $a = bx$ and $b = ay$. Also show that $y$ is then the inverse of $x$ and that these elements $x$ and $y$ are unique (for $a$ and $b$ given).

I don't see how I can show the existence of invertible elements, $x$ and $y$. Also for the second proof if I substitute the two equations
$a = bx = ayx$ because of the integral domain of $A$ we have $1 = xy$ so then  $y$ is the inverse of $x$. I don't see after that how I can show that $x$ and $y$ are unique. If anyone as any idea let me know.

Comment: In an integral domain $R$ with fraction field $K$ we have a group homomorphism $K^* \to I(R), a\to aR$ (where $aR$ is a sub-$R$-module of $K$) whose kernel is $R^\times$. Thus $(a)=(b)$ iff $a=ub$ with $u\in R^\times$.

Comment: You already showed that $xy = 1$ which implies that $x$ and $y$ are units. For uniqueness, you can divide by $b$ of $a = bx = bx'$. I suppose that $a \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what the semantics of "commutative ring over an integral domain" are all about, but if $A$ *is* an integral domain, and assuming $(a)$ denotes the principal ideal generated by $a$, that is,

$(a) = aA, \tag 1$

then since $A$ has a unit $1_A$,

$a = a1_A \in aA = (a), \tag 2$

and likewise

$b \in (b); \tag{2.5}$

thus from

$(a) = (b) \tag 3$

we infer that

$a \in (b), \; b \in (a), \tag 4$

and hence

$\exists x, y: a = bx, \; b = ay, \tag 5$

leading to

$a = (ay)x = a(xy), \tag 6$

or

$a(1_A - xy) = a - a(xy) = a - a = 0; \tag 6$

if we now hypothesize that

$a \ne 0, \tag 7$

the assumption that $A$ is an integral domain forces

$xy = 1_A, \tag 8$

that is, both $x$ and $y$ are invertible and

$y = x^{-1}, \; x = y{-1}. \tag 9$

The uniqueness of $x$ is seen *via*

$bx = a = bx' \Longrightarrow b(x - x') = 0 \Longrightarrow x - x' = 0 \Longrightarrow x = x', \tag{10}$

provided of course

$b \ne 0; \tag{11}$

thus $x$ is unique; a similar argument applies to $y$.

We observe that (7) and (11) are equivalent since both imply (8)-(9).  In the event that

$a = 0, \tag{12}$

we also have

$b = 0, \tag{13}$

since we have shown that

$a \ne 0 \Longleftrightarrow b \ne 0; \tag{14}$

this also follows from

$a = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (a) = aA = \{0\} \Longleftrightarrow bA = (b) = (a) = \{0\} \Longleftrightarrow b = 0. \tag{15}$

Comment: @ola:  it is necessary to cover the case $a = b = 0$; the way I wrote the proof assumed $a \ne 0$ at (7), so for the case of completeness I wanted to cover $a = b = 0$.  I admit the $a = b = 0$ case is a pretty simple addition.  Does this aswer you query?  Cheers!